# what happens to standard output in a Swing program?

Tags: java, linux, swing

As a test I wrote to linux's standard output from a Swing program and there is no visible console.  It does not crash.  No exception is thrown.  Is this known to be safe?  I have no intention to do this in general but it could happen if there is a bug in the program.

Edit: The question was rephrased to remove all mention of the Java object System.out.  There is a console to receive and display standard output data in the Eclipse IDE but obviously my question pertains to when there is no IDE.

Comment: why wouldn't it be safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Java program is still a program, and pretty much every program in Linux gets three streams: input, output, and error.  Java's `in`, `out` and `err` sit on top of those streams.

If you were to start the program from the command line like `java YourApp`, you'd more than likely see output from those streams appear in your console.  Or a debugger would be able to capture them and do likewise.  But in an app that's started from the GUI, the output pretty much just gets forgotten about.

Short version: yes, it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

It writes to stdout, just like in any Java app. It's up to the OS what stdout is and where the output shows up, but just because an app shows a GUI window doesn't make it any different. You can make a webapp show a window, and you can still write to stdout from there, too.

Comment: Excuse my wrong terminology.  I will rephrase the question to "what happens when I write to linux's standard output when there is no console".

Answer (score 0):

If you launched the program from the command line then the System.out will be written to that window. If you launched the program

Answer (score 0):

It goes to the standard output stream. But there may be or there may be not some console associated with the current JVM.

If you run your application from a terminal (command or whatever they call it on windows systems) you'll be able to see your output almost the same way you see at eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you're not writing to Linux's stdout, you're writing to the java System.out object. It's possible for Java applications to redirect System.out to a different output stream, so there's no guarantee where the output will go at the OS level. That said, it's safe to write to System.out from a Swing application, in that it won't cause anything to blow up.

Just don't write any sensitive information out, thinking it won't go anywhere.